# Why is "Build configurations..." not available in Eclipse CDT with QT eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, qt, configuration, build, eclipse-cdt

I have Eclipse Helios with CDT and Qt plugin installed. After creating a new Qt project it´s not possible to select a build configuration (release or debug) using the "hammer icon" like I do it in normal C++ projects.

Default is building in debug mode. To change to "release" you have to go to "Project > Properties > C/C++ Make Project > Make Builder > Workbench Build Behaviour > Build (Incremental Build)" and type "debug" or "release".

So my question is: why is that and how can I change it?

Thanks a lot,

Sebastian

Comment: This was a factor for me moving to NetBeans for C++/Qt development. I wanted to use Eclipse but the "disconnect" between Eclipse and Qt projects was too much. Qt Creator has since filled this gap and continues to improve by leaps and bounds. I do wish however that Qt could have put that kind of effort into an Eclipse integration.

Comment: I like working with eclipse too. But eclipse + qt plugin isn´t fun at all. I will try QtCreator. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is a bug/feature request of the CDT project.  The standard Eclipse plugins that handle builds don't know anything about the CDT.  The CDT plugin needs to provide extensions to the Build feature to handle what you describe.

Comment: So it´s rather a bug in CDT than in the Qt plugin? But aren´t there other plugins (from the same type like the Qt plugin) which doesn´t have that problem? I´m also using a plugin for fujitsu mcu´s which works fine. I use this plugin with an "External builder", perhaps that´s the solution... (There a 2 possible options: "Internal builder" or "External builder").

Comment: It could be in the Qt plugin. For internal builders, the plugin needs to do the integration with the build system.  If you use an External builder, you get to provide your own script for it.  Try the External approach and see if you get enough control to be a workaround.